# Why Can not see the preview of this image in android studio?

Tags: android, image

I dont know why I can not use this image.

The image is a 200x200px .png file
 [image]

This is how looks in android studio, [image]

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you try to use the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your image is too big(kb size) you cant see a preview like ic_launcher,but still working normally.

Answer (score 1):

So I can see that you want to store a bunch of that image in an array called `data`. I think the image you want to use is called `ll.png`. But you used

```
R.drawable.ic_launcher
```

to refer to it. I don't know who would ever use "ic_launcher" to mean "ll". You should refer to that `ll.png` like this:

```
R.drawable.ll
```

I mean that is the most logical thing to do, right?